# Populating form from table row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I have added a button at the end of the row of my datatable intended to update the information in the database for the specific row chosen.

When I click the update button, a form pops us with the relevant fields to update.

Ideally, I would like the form to be autopopulated with the information from the table row which I have chosen to update

Code...

Table:

```
<div class="viewalljob tab-pane show active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <h2>Edit Job Table</h2>
    <table id="edit-job-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="job_id">ID</th>
                <th class="job_date">Date</th>
                <th class="job_company">Company Name</th>
                <th class="job_contact">Contact</th>
                <th class="job_from">From</th>
                <th class="job_to">To</th>
                <th class="job_driver nowrap">Driver</th>
                <th class="job_income">Income (£)</th>
                <th class="job_payment">Payment (£)</th>                        
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--Fetch from Database-->
            <!--Connect To Database-->
            <?php
            $host_name = 'xxx';
            $database = 'xxx';
            $user_name = 'xxx';
            $password = 'xxx';
            $conn = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

            // Check connection

            if (!$conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            $sql = "SELECT *,AS markup
                    FROM `table`
                    GROUP BY id";
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    echo "<tr>
                    <td class='job_id'>".$result['id']."</td>
                    <td class='job_date'>".$result['adddate']."</td>
                    <td class='job_company'>".$result['customer']."</td>
                    <td class='job_contact'>".$result['addcontact']."</td>
                    <td class='nowrap job_from'>".$result['addfrom']."</td>
                    <td class='nowrap job_to'>".$result['addto']."</td>
                    <td class='nowrap job_driver'>".$result['adddriver']."</td>
                    <td class='currency job_income'>".$result['addincome']."</td>
                    <td class='currency job_payment'>".$result['addpayment']."</td>
                    <td><button type='button' name='update' id=".$result['id']." class='btn btn-warning btn-xs update updatebtn'>Update</button></td>
                    <td><button type='button' name='delete' id=".$result['id']." class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete deletebtn'>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>";
                }
            } else { 
                echo "0 results";
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="contactForm3">
    <h1>Edit Job</h1>
    <form id="dataForm" name="dataform" method="POST" action="/">
        /**** FORM DATA ****/
    </form>
</div>
```

JS to open form:

```
$(function() {
    // contact form animations
    $('.update').click(function() {
        $('#contactForm3').fadeToggle();
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#contactForm3");

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

I have added the update button using `<td><button type='button' name='update' id=".$result['id']." class='btn btn-warning btn-xs update updatebtn'>Update</button></td>` I have given the `id=".$result['id']."` hoping that I can use this to populate the form from the `ID`

I am assuming that I will need to connect to the database table, something like:

```
<form>
<?php
//Connect to Database ... //
$sql = SELECT * FROM `table`
       WHERE ID = ???

       $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

       if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          echo "<span>
                    <label> label1 </label>
                        <input value = ".$result['column'].">
                </span>";
                        }
                    } else { 
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                    ?>
```

Im hoping that this is correct and someone can help me do this?

Comment: What exactly is your question? *"Im hoping that this is correct and someone can help me do this?"* is not very clear. Could you specify which part exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: @Dharman I have a datatable with an update button at the end of each row. the update button has been given `id=".$result['id']."` so that its ID liks up with the ID of the particular row. when I click update, I would like it to populate the update form with the details from the table row and am hoping that usin `id=".$result['id']."` will help me achieve that

Comment: Ok, what is the last PHP code about then? If your question is about the UI behaviour then why PHP code in your post?

Comment: @Dharman I have added the PHP as I am assuming that I would need to use PHP to pull the current data from the database to the populate the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can acheive this using javascript/jquery, get row element from table displayed, from which you can get every columns/inputs value like as below:

```
$('.updatebtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); //get table row from displayed table.
    var form = $('#contactForm3').fimd('form'); //form to be populate.
    //make sure your form input field with same name as the column name.
    //now create form_data object with key as same name as column/input name .
    var form_data = { 'id' : row.find('.job_id').value(),
                    'adddate' : row.find('.job_date').value(),
                    .....
                    'addpayment' : row.find('.job_payment').value()
                    }

    //Apply loop to populate values in form.
    $.each(form_data, function(key, value){
        form.find('input[name="'+ key +'"]').val(value);
    });

});
```

Then on form submit update database record/row using PHP (hope you know that well, if not let me know I will update my code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added that JS in place of my own. but the update form (#contactform3) did not open, so I changed `var form = $('#contactForm3').find('form');` to `var form = $('#contactForm3').fadeToggle('form');`, so the form now opens, but it does not populate from the table. are there any changes I should make?

Comment: If I keep the form displayed constantly and position in above (or below the table) I can populate the form by clicking on a row, using: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td", this).on("click", function () {
        var tds = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(tds, function (i, v) {
            $($(".dataForm3 input")[i]).val($(v).text());
        });
    });
});`  If I could adapt this to work when i click the update button, for the form to appear with the correct field info

Comment: Figured it out with a mixture of your code and that I pasted above :-)

Comment: Sorry! apologize for not replying to you on time. But I had only given the solution for how to populate values in the form. But still, I appreciate your efforts to find solutions ownself.